# What better implementation for JSAPI (Java Speech API) with Java EE (JSF)?

Tags: java, voice-recognition, jsapi

I'm searching for an implementation of JSAPI that can be used with Java EE (JSF).
What implementation is better with JSF?

The examples that I found, don't have an implementation for java web.
The installation is in the web server or the local machine user's in for this case?

Comment: FreeTTS             or         
IBM's Speech for Java. The oficial sites have a documentation, but i don't find the implementation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use JSAPI, it's pretty obsolete and somewhat useless API. It was never successful as a standard.

Just use CMUSphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Comment: Thanks! I'm find the web site: http://wehavescience.com/2012/11/03/reconhecimento-de-voz-com-sphinx-4/

Comment: This is very outdated information, sphinx4 has significantly changed since then.